# Apache responses with http/1.0 even if request is http/1.1

Tags: apache, http, proxy, mod-proxy

I configured Apache Http server version 2.4 as proxy for backend server (Glassfish App Server actually). MPM is `worker`.

Configuration is mostly default. Configuration for proxy

```
ProxyPass /context/ http://backend.com:8080/context/ keepalive=On ttl=25 timeout=300 max=50
ProxyPassReverse /context/ http://backend.com:8080/context/
```

I open page in browser and it sends `GET http://example.com/context HTTP/1.1` to Apache. Apache returns response `HTTP/1.0 200 OK` with `Connection: close` header. But actual backend server response contains `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`.

Why does Apache downgrade proxied response from 1.1 to 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

`force-no-vary` is the cause. Documentation says:

> **force-no-vary** This causes any Vary fields to be removed from the
>   response header before it is sent back to the client. Some clients
>   don't interpret this field correctly; setting this variable can work
>   around this problem. Setting this variable also implies
>   force-response-1.0.
>
> **force-response-1.0** This forces an HTTP/1.0 response to clients making
>   an HTTP/1.0 request. It was originally implemented as a result of a
>   problem with AOL's proxies. Some HTTP/1.0 clients may not behave
>   correctly when given an HTTP/1.1 response, and this can be used to
>   interoperate with them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case we were writing PHP using HTTPFoundation's Response object. It defaults to HTTP/1.0.