# How to connect Jenkins Slave Agents using websocket and master node behind Apache reverse proxy

Tags: apache, jenkins, websocket, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to connect a new jenkins slave node using websocket, launching the agent from slave node the response to wss call is 400 Bad request, that is receipt from agent as an "handshake error".
From my low level tests and analysis I found that incoming calls in Apache reverse proxy in HTTP/1.1 are downgraded to HTTP/1.0 when forwarded to destination node and then upgraded to HTTP/1.1 when response returned to caller. I didn't found any configuration to avoid this.

### Detailed description

**Architecture**

- Apache Reverse Proxy, version 2.4.41, installed in a RHEL7.3, IP
  192.168.1.2
  Apache it is behind a public firewall and only port 443 is allowed, https it is offloaded in apache virtualhost. The
  communications between Apache and Jenkins Master node is in http on
  port 8080
- Jenkins Master node version 2.263.1, installed in a
  RHEL7.6, Openjdk11, IP 192.168.1.10:8080
  (NO "It appears that your
  reverse proxy setup is broken" message is showed in jenkins)
- Jenkins Slave node, agent installed in a Windows server 2016, Openjdk11, IP
  192.168.1.11
  (Master and Slave nodes are in same subnet and ideally don't need to be connected passing through public network. I didn't
  found a way about this, it is allowed only for jnlp by setting
  hudson.TcpSlaveAgentListener.hostName system property, reference:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39965700 and
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39136802)

**Reverse Proxy Configuration**

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"

SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

ProxyRequests Off
AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

<Location /jenkins>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://192.168.1.10:8080/jenkins nocanon
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.1.10:8080/jenkins
    ProxyPassReverse https://my.public.fqdn.com/jenkins

    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host "my.public.fqdn.com"
</Location>

<Location /jenkins/wsagents>
    ### Configurations tested and commented, not working ###
    #SetEnv force-no-vary 1
    #SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
    #SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    #RequestHeader unset Expect early

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass ws://192.168.1.10:8080/jenkins/wsagents
    ProxyPassReverse ws://192.168.1.10:8080/jenkins/wsagents
</Location>
```

**Behaviour**
Created in jenkins a new Node from "Manage Nodes and Cloud" and selected "Launch Agent by connecting it to the master" from "Launch method", and selected "Use Websocket",
when I try to launch the agent from slave node I experienced an 400 Bad request response falling in handshake error:

```
java -jar agent.jar -jnlpUrl https://my.public.fqdn.com/jenkins/computer/Slave%20Windows/slave-agent.jnlp -secret @secret-file -workDir "E:\JenkinsSlave"

Sending handshake request:
> GET wss://my.public.fqdn.com/jenkins/wsagents/
> Connection: Upgrade
> Host: my.public.fqdn.com
> Node-Name: Slave Windows
> Origin: my.public.fqdn.com
> Sec-WebSocket-Key: FFGODSDcF0TTP4q/usk9Bw==
> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
> Secret-Key: 123123123123
> Upgrade: websocket
> X-Remoting-Capability: rO0ABXNyABpod4ucmVtbpbmcuQ2FwYWJpbGl0eQAAAAAAAAABAgABSgAEbWFza3hwAAAAf4=

2021-01-14T22:48:44.776+0100 FINE io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.DebugContext flush: < Session 36d3c733-37f3-4f6e-bea1-920e8cf6f3da [128 ms]: Received handshake response: 
< 400
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store
< Content-Length: 533
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
< Cookie: 52d4f682f884de63b52ae34622c7f3968acfc365d02327e2eec34f1f8e1
< Server: Jetty(9.4.33.v20201020)
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Remoting-Capability: rO0ABXNyABpod4ucmVtbpbmcuQ2FwYWJpbGl0eQAAAAAAAAABAgABSgAEbWFza3hwAAAAf4=
< X-Remoting-Minimum-Version: 3.14

SEVERE hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error: Handshake error.
io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Handshake error.
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:674)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:355)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.runWebSocket(Engine.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:470)
Caused by: io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 400.
```

In Jenkins master node logs I found (System log Level set to ALL):

> WARNING   o.e.j.w.s.WebSocketServerFactory#isUpgradeRequest: Not a
> 'HTTP/1.1' request (was [HTTP/1.0])

**The question is**
Why apache reverse proxy switches HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/1.0 for websocket communications to backend, and how to fix it?
I tried many configurations in apache with no luck (i.e. force-no-vary)

**Reference**
[Apache responses with http/1.0 even if request is http/1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266860/apache-responses-with-http-1-0-even-if-request-is-http-1-1)
[Jenkins: How to configure Jenkins behind Nginx reverse proxy for JNLP slaves to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38729686/jenkins-how-to-configure-jenkins-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-jnlp-slaves-to/39965700#39965700)

Answer (score 3):

For the second part (how to fix it) the following additions to the apache config worked for me. It uses the answer to this question: [WebSocket through SSL with Apache reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552164/websocket-through-ssl-with-apache-reverse-proxy)

Specifically:

```
# allow for upgrading to websockets
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:8080/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass "/jenkins/wsagents" "ws://localhost:8080/jenkins/wsagents"
ProxyPassReverse "/jenkins/wsagents" "ws://localhost:8080/jenkins/wsagents"
```

With mod_rewrite and mod_proxy_wstunnel enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately your solution does not work with the explained configuration, I continue to receive "handshake error" as above